# Check if character field contains only digits

Tags: abap

I read data from a excel file.
The cols of internal table all are char128, there are 2 cols contain only digital with decimal point. So I need to check the fields only contain digital or digital with decimal point.

The function module NUMERIC_CHECK, just can check only digital, if the digital with decimal point it will be useless.

Comment: yes,actually it could be any thing, I just wanna check it, if it could be convert to digital, I have to show a error message to user

Answer (score 6):

You may use `CO` (contains only):

```
IF value CO '1234567890.'.
  "OK
ELSE.
  "Error"
ENDIF.
```

Maybe you need also a space in your `IF _ CO`-statement.

This check does not detect multiple decimals points  (e.g. `123.45.67.89`).

Newer versions of ABAP support regular expressions.

If you have also spaces in your string, you may add them into the CO-value:: `IF value CO '1234567890 .'.`

Comment: it's not a best one, I have tried it, if the value has space in it, it will be useless

Comment: @YuTian You may add spaces in your comparison. I modified my answer,

Comment: This technique is virtually useless since it will also let complete nonsense like "... . .. .. ." pass.

Answer (score 5):

You might try to use REGEX. The report DEMO_REGEX_TOY lets you input strings and test regular expressions against them.

Someone more experienced with REGEX in general might be able to make this a little more versatile but here's what I came up with:

```
-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?
```

**-?** Optionally match the '-' character (allows for negatives or non-negatives

**[0-9]+** matches digits (the + makes it match 1 or more)

**\.?** optionally matches the '.' character (the \ is needed as '.' is an operator)

**([0-9]+)?** optionally matches any digits after the decimal

Comment: Rather use `(?:)` instead of `()` for non-submatch grouping.

Comment: This will fail on `-.5` , Refined regex: `-?(?:[0-9]+\.?|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the string is a valid decimal, you could use the following module function : 'HRCM_STRING_TO_AMOUNT_CONVERT', which allow you to convert a string to its numeric counterpart, given the string, the decimal separator and the thousand separator.

regards

Answer (score -1):

Another way to check for number:

```
data: float_value type f.
try.
  float_value = <your string value here>.
catch cx_sy_conversion_no_number.
  " not a valid number
endtry.
```

Comment: throwing exception is not a best way to check, it requires additional memory